# Why does this JavaScript code only work when I run it on a HTTP server?

Tags: javascript, api, http, server, google-calendar-api

I am trying to build a Chrome Extension which uses the Google Calendar API. I am trying to avoid having to setup a server just to make API calls to Google Calendar. I tried following the example here:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js#step_2_set_up_the_sample

But that code requires me to have a HTTP Server running. Why does that code only work when I run it on an HTTP Server? From what I can see, its only JavaScript and HTML, which should work when I run it locally on my browser (using the file:// protocol). I also don't see any CORS issues either.

I could probably just setup a Heroku server, but I'm trying to understand why this seemingly client side code requires a server to run!

Comment: Probably because `file://` origins are prohibited from doing some things in browser Javascript so they just want you to load the HTML page from a "real" web server.  Did you try it when just loaded directly from the file system?  Did it work or what errors did you encounter?  I also see something in Step 1 about `Authorized JavaScript origins` which means your web page might need a real origin also.

Comment: probably it's doing an http (e.g. ajax) request somewhere, and code loaded from a `file:///` url can NOT do ajax.

Comment: file:// protocol is not prohibited in javascript it's upto the browsers. And yes chrome does block when you try to  hit an google api/some https request from local file for security reasons. While I have seen some of them working in FF.

Comment: @MarcB certain HTTP requests are allowed from file://. I know this because I am able to see in the firefox developer console that the script.js file is being retrieved google's servers using a GET request.

Comment: @JanacMeena: yes, but that's just a `<script src=...` thing. even a file:///-based html page will load external images with `<img src=...`. but you can't do an ajax request from that file:///-loaded page. that'd be a violation of same-origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers prevent Javascript in web pages loaded from a `file://` URL from doing some things for security reasons, such as making ajax calls.

So, since this code is ultimately making some Ajax calls out to a calendar server, the code probably wants to make sure your web page is not restricted by these security limitations so it is suggesting a way that the web page can be loaded from a local web server, rather than the file system and thus it won't have any restrictions applied to pages loaded with `file://` URLs.

It's worth mentioning that the security restrictions applied to `file://` URLs are browser-specific (each browser makes it's own choices as to what to restrict).  Chrome seems to be fairly restrictive in this regard (though I think there is a command line argument that can relax some of these restrictions).

Comment: Ah that makes sense - When creating the app, I have to set which JavaScript origins that I want to allow, in the Google Developer Console. I only have the localhost set here, so it only makes sense that a file:// url would not work. I suppose I should search up why loading js file from your file system is more dangerous than running a simple web server and running the same javascript file.